# How do waves relate to this?

Tags: meaning, mandarin, sentence-structure, proverb

*Please write using **simplified** Chinese characters.*

I've been reading a short story in Chinese, with the task to translate it. Here's the passage I'm having trouble with:

> ‘看了，看了，他的那个女朋友真不像话，见他在报上登了几篇小说就主动爱上了他，课知道了他是一个清洁工，并打算干一辈子，就又甩了人家，真太可恶了。’
>   左边的那位留波浪式发的抢看回答。

There are two issues I have with this piece. What I'm having trouble understanding is that last sentence:

> 左边的那位留波浪式发的抢看回答。

I understand the meaning of this sentence, which is that the girl on the left was the first to answer. However, what role do the following bits of this sentence have?:

- 留
- 波浪 (wave?)
- 式发

To be honest, it's probably just another Chinese proverb I'm not aware of.

Thanks!

Comment: My guess: "左边的那位留波浪式发型的抢着回答。". `波浪式发型` -> `wave hair`.

Comment: 留:with, 波浪式, wave-style, 发:hair.     XX式=xx style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

留 means 'maintain' ; 'keep'; 'grew (of hair or beard)'

波浪 means 'wave'

式 means 'style'

发 means 'hair'

> 波浪式= [wavy style](https://www.pinterest.com/explore/wavy-hairstyles/)
>
> 留波浪式发(型) = has wavy hair (style)

It is common to identify someone by something unique in his or her appearance, like hair styles, clothes color, etc.  when we don't know his or her name

Answer (score 1):

留波浪式发 is a perm.

The original Chinese has issues. We tidied them up like this. Maybe it is a conversation in a hairdresser's salon.
“看了，看了，
I know, I know,
他的那个女朋友真不像话，
his girlfriend is really outrageous,
她见他在报上登了几篇小说就主动爱上了他，
she saw him publish a few short stories in the newspaper and decided to fall in love with him,
可当她知道了他是一个清洁工，
but when she found out that he is a cleaner,
并打算干一辈子后，
and plans to do that  all his life,
就又甩了人家，
she left him,
真是太可恶了。”
she really is repulsive.”
左边的那位留波浪式发的女士抢着回答。
the woman on the left with the perm rushed to answer.